# How do create colored rectangle boxes inside one another using divs i have added the picture below to show an example of what i want to do

Tags: jquery, html, css

//I have added the picture below [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgnxY.png)

Comment: what you have tried so far? what are the bottlenecks you met?

Comment: I have this so far https://codepen.io/FDeJesus/pen/VxjoZx

Comment: No one can see what you have posted without leaving this site. That's not how this works. Please post your code in your question. I haven't down voted you, but you can see that others have.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score -1):

Except the border color you need using JavaScript, I think this snippet is almost meet your need.

```js
// random color
function cc () { return Math.round(Math.random() * 254); }
function color () {
  return "rgb(" + [ cc(), cc(), cc() ] + ")";
}

var main = document.getElementById("main");

main.style.borderColor = color();
while (main.firstElementChild) {
  main = main.firstElementChild;
  main.style.borderColor = color();
}
```

```css
div {
  /* color omitted and it will assign with javascript */
  border: 1px solid;
}

#main { width: 400px; height: 600px; position: relative; }

div > div {
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- changed the "class" attribute as "id" -->
<div id="main">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <div>
                <div></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yea that works but how would i change the color inside each rectangle

Comment: A little modification on snippet above.